# Tabbar iPad App to Sidebar macOS Catalyst app

Tags: ios, xcode, mac-catalyst

I am struggling to figure out how to turn my `tabbar` based iPad app into a sidebar navigation based `Catalyst` app. Similar to the screenshot that Apple shows:

[image]

You can see in the screenshot above the iPad app uses a `tabbar` layout but the `macOS` Catalyst app used a left sidebar navigation.

**How can I do this and convert my iPad app to use a sidebar in `macOS`?**

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```swift
#if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
    // here use the NavigationView + NavigationLinks to make the sidebar on macOS
#else
    // here use the Tab Bar view. 
#endif
```

You can use this to create entire alternate views if you need.

For example:

```swift
#if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
struct MyView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Im in macOS")
    }
}
#else
struct MyView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Im in iOS")
    }
}
#endif
```